# Trouble Logging into Server: call to lnusertemp failed (temporary directories full ?).Check your installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication

We are running a Kubuntu Server, It has been running without any problems for a long time.
However, When attempting to login to the server through the GUI it throws the following error message:

> lnusertemp failed (temporary directories full ?). Check your installation

We have much free room on the drives and cannot figure out the cause of this issue. We are able to login through a remote cli application (using putty).

To my knowledge, we haven't updated or modified any core files or settings to this server, so its sudden change in operation has given us with some concern. This server is an important unit to our working process.